# style bootstrap with a row with multiple inputs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, bootstrap-5

I am looking for input/assistance with how you would style using bootstrap 5.

I created a codepen:
https://codepen.io/korazy/pen/xxmWGOx

Issues:

1. I have a row with text that my wrap, bootstrap now wants to change the input height to be the full height of the row.  I want the input to stay a proper height.
2. I have the word "to" between two inputs so the user can enter a range of values. I am looking for a proper way to align things both vertical and horizontal.
3. I have a select, when "equals" is selected only the first input is shown. When "between" is selected, it shows two inputs to enter a value range. Looking for input on how you would structure the html for this scenario.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#operator").on("change", function() {
    onOperatorChange($(this));
  });
});

function onOperatorChange(e) {
  const sb = e.closest("div.row").find("#show_b");
  if (e.val() == "e") {
    sb.addClass("visually-hidden");
  } else {
    sb.removeClass("visually-hidden");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a bit html

```
<div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center fixed-height-input">
  <input id="value" type="text" class="form-control" value="123" maxlength=5 style="max-width:100px;"/>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2 ms-1" id="show_b">
    to
  <input id="value_to" type="text" class="form-control fixed-height-input" value="456" maxlength=5 style="max-width:100px;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can check my version here:

https://codepen.io/uafrontender/pen/rNodVmE

It's not clear what did you mean in point 3. Seems it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I was missing the align-items-center.  For #3, I work solo so I was asking about if there is a better way of structuring my html for that scenario.

Comment: @user3720435 html looks ok as for me